# Using a switch for an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

so far i've been thinking this might be a good idea about what I want, but if is there any better ideas i'd be glad to check them out!

Here's my code:

```
int [] employeeId = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};
switch (employeeId)
{
case 5658845:
System.out.println(Hello User #1!);
break;
}
```

and so on, and so forth for the others ID's. It's it possible to do this?

Comment: If each number has a String to match it, I'd use a map instead.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to differ in the different outputs? The number?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the ids ?

Comment: when the user inputs the employee ID, the message should be displayed, it doesnt matter what the message is.

Comment: As @dambros said, use a Map instead of int[].

Answer (score 0):

It's possible something like that but it's not very efficient. 
First of all, you can't use an array in the `switch` like that.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

You should name your array `employeeList` or something like that. It's difficult to differenciate one employee's id from the entire group.

Let's assume that you got an employeeList and that employeeId is a single employee's id. What about this approach?

```
int index = Arrays.asList(employeeList).indexOf(employeeId);
System.out.println("Hello User #" + (index + 1) + "!");
```